# Is it possible to build href based on labels or values if checkbox is checked? (without js)

Tags: html

I want to create a link based on labels of values of checked checkboxes. In this way the content will vary depending on the chosen checkbox.

The platform where I use my code is forbidding the use of JavaScript, so I try to overcome the issue with pure HTML.

Here are the checkboxes:

```html
  <ul>
     <li>                                                               
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxDress" id="checkboxDress" 
       class="style-checkbox" value="Dress">                                                                    
       <label for="checkboxDress">Dress</label>                                                                    
     </li>                                                                  
     <li>                                                                  
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxLongsleeve" 
         id="checkboxLongsleeve" class="style-checkbox"
         value="Longsleeve"> 
       <label for="checkboxLongsleeve">Longsleeve</label>
     </li>
     <li>                                                                   
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxCoat" id="checkboxCoat" 
        class="style-checkbox" value="Coat">                                                                
     <label for="checkboxCoat">Coat</label>                                                              
     </li>                                                                                                              
  </ul>
```

and my `href` where I want to modify the existing link:

```
   <a href="http://www.ebaystores.de/familiare-store/_i.html?_nkw=">
      <div class="searchbtn">Search</div>
   </a>
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Without Javascript? No, not in it's current form. There would be no way for you to detect if a checkbox has been triggered. As @mplungjan says, a form would be the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a form

```html
<form action="http://www.ebaystores.de/familiare-store/_i.html">
  <input type="text" name="nkw" placeholder="Type your question" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxDress" id="checkboxDress" class="style-checkbox" value="Dress">
      <label for="checkboxDress">Dress</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxLongsleeve" id="checkboxLongsleeve" class="style-checkbox" value="Longsleeve">
      <label for="checkboxLongsleeve">Longsleeve</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxCoat" id="checkboxCoat" class="style-checkbox" value="Coat">
      <label for="checkboxCoat">Coat</label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button class="searchbtn">Search</button>
</form>
```

The above will create

```
http://www.ebaystores.de/familiare-store/_i.html?nkw=...&checkboxDress=Dress
```

If that is not useful, you need to send it to a server process that can read the checkboxes and create the link you want and redirect

Comment: thank you, your solution helped me a lot! however when I click on the button the link opens, but without the "nkw=" part, which is essential for href, because it points the keyword we want to find i.e. "dress" or "coat"... do you have any idea why is it missing?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can make the nkw type="hidden" and update it yourself from script or hardcode